# Why several apache2 processes are running? (screenshot)

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I just installed installed LAMP on Debian and I see following Apache processes running. Why so many of the same processes are running? What does it mean? Is it normal or have I done something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I’m not *specifically* familiar with Apache, but this seems fairly normal.  Is this on a closed system, *immediately* after you start up, or is it on an operational system?  If it’s an operational system, it’s almost surely normal; I would expect there to be at least one process for each connected client.

Answer (score 3):

Apache will pre-create worker processes so, when a load spike comes in, the processes can pick up the requests immediately, instead of waiting for the master to spawn enough of them. Check your httpd.conf for MinSpareServers, MaxSpareServers and ServerLimit.

- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568770/why-there-are-so-many-apache-processes-running)

Comment: And not to forget the [StartServers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers) directive.